# How do I render the name of an object (or dictionary?) in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Using python and jinja2, I want to print the key and value for an object if it exists. It seems it should be simple, but I can't get the output that I want: 
for an object that is
{"name1": "value1", "name2":"value2"} I would like to print

```
name1 = value1
name2 = value2
```

I can accomplish what I want with a jinja 2 parameter macro.

```
macro_2arg("name1", name1)
```

I would like to accomplish this by just providing the name object.

```
macro_1arg(name1)
```

I've tried a few things that don't work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from jinja2 import Template

tmpl_str = """
{%- macro macro_2arg(param_name, param) %}
    {%-if param is defined -%}
    {{param_name}} = {{param}}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
{%- macro macro_1arg(param) %}
    {%-if param is defined -%}
    {{param.name}} = {{param}}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}

{{parameter_2arg("name1", name1)}}
{{parameter_2arg("name2", name2)}}
{{parameter_1arg(name1)}}
{{parameter_1arg(name2)}}
"""

template = Template(tmpl_str)

rendered = template.render({"name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2", "name3":"value3"})
print (rendered)
```

This prints:

```
name1 = value1
name2 = value2
 = value1
 = value2
```

What is the correct way to get the "name" attribute of the value passed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible, unless you attach a `.name` property to the object yourself. You might find Ned Batchelder's essay [Facts and Myths About Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) enlightening.

Comment: So one (of the many) gaps in my understanding is what is actually passed to the jinja template for name. I understand the point you are making about the name attribute, but what is the "type" of param inside of macro_1arg and what services are available? An object that implements a __repr__ or a single item dictionary of {"name1":"value1"} of just a string with value "value1" bound to name1?